# Asset pipeline not loading script from rails-assets gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, angular-file-upload

I have added the [danial-farid--angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) library to my rails 4 app via rails assets. The main library loads fine, but sprockets can't find the shims file it includes for file upload progress. I think this is because the shims file is not in the same directory as the main `angular-file-upload.js` script. Is that likely to be the issue, or am I looking in the wrong place for the problem?

Details:

According to the home page on github:

`<!-- shim is needed to support upload progress/abort for HTML5 and non-HTML5 FormData browsers.-->`

In gemfile:

```
gem 'rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload'
```

In application.js:

```
//= require angular-file-upload-shim
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-file-upload
```

As is this generates a `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error:

`couldn't find file 'angular-file-upload-shim'`

If I remove the first require above, the asset pipeline loads everything else fine, but it breaks the things that rely on the shims file.

A grep of the gems directory reveals:

```
rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload
rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.js
rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload/FileAPI.min.js
rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js
rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload-html5-shim.js
rails-assets-danialfarid--angular-file-upload-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload.js
```

I can see that there is an `angular-file-upload.js` in the gem's `vendor/assets/javascripts`  directory while the `angular-file-upload-shim.js` file is in a subdirectory of that folder. Is that sufficient to break the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to ad the sub directory. i.e.

```
//= require angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim
```